# Recommended way to get Co-ordinated cluster time off chain

Tags: transactions, time, rpc, deserialization

Q1.What is the recommended way to fetch current cluster co-ordinated timestamp ? is it via fetching the clock account and deserializing it if so is there a method which takes care of deserializing it,
Q2   there exists something along the lines of getParsedAccountInfo but i dont understand how is it possible for it decode any account info without having knowledge of the underlying Structure.

Comment: Please make one post per question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the timestamp of the last processed block quite easily if that's sufficient:

```
const slot = await connection.getSlot({ commitment: 'processed' });
const timestamp = await connection.getBlockTime(slot);
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a cleaner way to do this but you can fetch the clock sysvar and the decode it using the following snippet:

```
import { AccountInfo, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { BN } from 'bn.js'

export const SYSVAR_OWNER_PUBKEY = new PublicKey(
  'Sysvar1111111111111111111111111111111111111'
)

interface Clock {
  slot: number
  epochStartTimestamp: number
  epoch: number
  leaderScheduleEpoch: number
  unixTimestamp: number
}

export function decodeSysvarClock(info: AccountInfo<Buffer>): Clock {
  if (!info.owner.equals(SYSVAR_OWNER_PUBKEY) || info.data.length !== 40) {
    throw new Error('invalid clock account')
  }

  return {
    slot: new BN(info.data.slice(0, 7), undefined, 'le').toNumber(),
    epochStartTimestamp: new BN(
      info.data.slice(8, 15),
      undefined,
      'le'
    ).toNumber(),
    epoch: new BN(info.data.slice(16, 23), undefined, 'le').toNumber(),
    leaderScheduleEpoch: new BN(
      info.data.slice(24, 31),
      undefined,
      'le'
    ).toNumber(),
    unixTimestamp: new BN(info.data.slice(32, 39), undefined, 'le').toNumber(),
  }
}
```