# How to get the Solana unix_timestamp on the front-end (in JavaScript)?

Tags: solana-program, javascript

Solana Rust onchains program have access to

```
solana_program::clock::Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp
```

which is seconds from epoch (midnight Jan 1st 1970 GMT) but has a significant drift from any real-world time-zone as a product of Solana's slowdowns over time. Many contracts factor in this unix timestamp when calculating reward amounts (notably Step Finance and therefore Gem Farm which reuses the logic). How can I reconstruct this Solana unix timestamp on the front-end in JavaScript without requiring any transaction / wallet signature? Calls to a Solana node RPC are fine.

Comment: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/82/recommended-way-to-get-co-ordinated-cluster-time-off-chain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `getBlockTime` endpoint from JSON RPC. First you'll need the highest slot using the `getSlot`. That would become:

```
const connection = new Connection('https://api.testnet.solana.com', 'processed');
const slot = await connection.getSlot();
const timestamp = await connection.getBlockTime(slot);
```

More info at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblocktime and https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getslot